# My Bibliography Does Not Appear

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

The bibliography doesn't appear in the next code, I am exporting the bibliography from a `.bib` file, the `.bib` file is a TeX document called `sample.bib` that I've modified replacing the extension by `.bib`, besides I've created a document called `sample.bib` that was a plain text, but the bibliography doesn't appear either.

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\title{Propuesta de Investigación\\Analisis de bifurcaciónes de Codimension- 2 en un Modelo de Desarrollo sostenible\vspace{5cm}\\}
\author{Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}


\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not shout at us! It isn't a great way to greet people you are asking for help.

Comment: You need a `bibliographystyle{}` command. You need to cite the entries you want to use in your document. Then you need to compile, run `bibtex` and compile twice more. Your `.bib` file should be a database of entries - not a TeX document. Don't put line breaks in the arguments of commands such as `\author{}` and `\title{}`. `mathtools` loads `amsmath`; `tikz` loads `pgf`; `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`.

Comment: Here is the classic reference on [how to use BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/).

Comment: Some times, I have experienced a similar problem, suddenly the bibliography does not show in the document. It usually means there is  a syntax error in the .bib file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in your code are two errors causing that the bibliography can not be displayed.

The first one is that you have to add an command `\bibliographystyle{...}` to define the layout of the resulting bibliography, for example you can use `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`.

The second error is that you need to cite one or more bib entries to get a bibliography printed.  Or you can use command `\nocite{*}` to get all uncited bib entries printed in the bibliography.

The following code (MWE) compiles with the wanted result:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\title{Propuesta de Investigación\\Analisis de bifurcaciónes de Codimension- 2 en un Modelo de Desarrollo sostenible\vspace{5cm}\\}
\author{Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

Text~\cite{adams} % citing one bib entry % <============================
\nocite{*}   % all not cited bib entrys are shown in bibliography ...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <===========================================
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use file created by filecontents ...

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image]

Comment: I most copy all the code  and compile it, or I must copy the first part in other kind of archive? Becouse if I copy all the document in a .tex extension document, the bibliography do not appear and the citation either.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Do you talk about my MWE or about your code? In my MWE I only used package `filecontents` to have bib entries and tex code concatenated in one compiling tex code. You use you own bib file and therefore have to change the used name in the call of `\bibliography` ...

Comment: How do I use my own .bib file, how do i create it?